# Excel macro "type mismatch" error while looping through a column

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch, mismatch

Every call of this Function results in a Runtime Error '13' Type Mismatch.  Why does this happen?

```
Public Function VersionExists(versionId As String)

   VersionExists = False

   For Each cell In Tabelle2.Columns(1)
      If cell.Value = versionId Then
         VersionExists = True
      End If
   Next

End Function
```

Comment: Use `Option Explicit`, please! You will have to declare all variabled explicitly, but it will drastically reduce the number of errors of this kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative as I suggested in the comment

```
Public Function VersionExists(versionId As String) As Boolean
    Dim aCell As Range, rng As Range

    Set rng = Tabelle2.Columns(1)

    Set aCell = rng.Find(What:=versionId, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then VersionExists = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't access `cell.value` from `.Columns(1)` as it returns a range encompassing the entire column, instead;

```
For Each cell In Sheet1.Columns(1).Rows '//or .cells
```

Probably a good idea to exit the for loop after a match too.

Comment: + 1 I would also recommend using `.Find` instead of looping